# Require another file in php class objects

Tags: php, class

Suppose I have the following code:

**a.php**

```
<?

class H{

    public $i = 123;

    public function S(){
        require "b.php";
        die;
    }
}

$i = new H();
$i -> S();
```

**b.php**

```
<?

echo $i->i;
```

However, system throws an error in file b.php that ***variable i is not defined***.

How can I fix this problem?

If it's possible, could someone kindly tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Look into [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should never include a file like that in case of OOP. As oop and procedural PHP is different. Whenever you want to echo anything inside the class you should use $this keyword that signifies that you are working in context of current class object. So thats why your code is not working and you are getting that variable i is not defined. As nathanael said its not an elegant way of coding

Answer (score 0):

you can write in b.php

```
echo $this->i;
```

and that would work, but that is not an elegant way of coding,

alternatively you can make `$i` accessible in `S()` in `a.php` you would have

```
public function S(){
    global $i;
    require "b.php";
    die;
}
```

And that would work also, but is no more elegant

when you require `b.php` in the method `S()`, it will inject the code from `b.php` inside the method `S()`, and there is no variable `$i`

you have a global variable `$i`, which is not accessible from `S()` unless you explicitly make it accessible